# list all users and show all post made by user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise and I wounder how I can make a view so that the view will list all users and when I click on a user it will show all the post that are made by that user. I just cant figure it out.

I can list all the users, but when I want to click on a user and list all the post that the user have done from ratter.

-------------my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :ratter
 end
```

-------------my ratter model

```
class Ratter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

-------------my view

```
<h1>List all users </h1>

<% @user.each do |user| %>
 <%= user.email %>
 <%= link_to 'show', user %>
<% end %>
```

-------------my view

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @user = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the user posts throught the association, like this:

```
@user.ratter
```

And then in your show view you can simply iterate throught them, and use the path method to generate a link to the post:

```
<% @user.ratter.each do |ratter| %>
 <%= link_to ratter.title, ratter_path(ratter) %>
<% end %>
```

You can run 'rails console' to play around and test things. Note that you will need to add 'app' for the path commands while in there. Like this:

```
app.ratter_path(1)
```